Index was outside the bounds of the array. C# Unity player prefs
Пишу текстовый квест на юнити, делаю сейчас сохранение и загрузку. Вот код основного скрипта:
using System;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[Serializable]
public class Action
{
    public string Description;
    public byte Index;
    public AudioClip ClickClip;
}

[Serializable]
public class Room
{
    public string Description;
    public Action[] Actions;

    public Texture BG;
    public AudioClip Clip;
}

public class TextQuest : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private TMP_Text _roomDesc;

    [SerializeField]
    private Button[] _actionButtons;

    [SerializeField]
    private TMP_Text[] _actionTexts;

    [SerializeField]
    private RawImage _background;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource _bgAudio;

    [SerializeField]
    private AudioSource _clickAudio;

    [SerializeField]
    private Room[] _roomInfo;

    [SerializeField]
    private int _currentIndex = 0;

    [SerializeField]
    private byte savedIndex;


    private void SetRoomInfo()
    {
        var currentRoom = _roomInfo[_currentIndex];
        var currentRoomActions = currentRoom.Actions;

        _roomDesc.text = currentRoom.Description;
        _background.texture = currentRoom.BG;

        for (var i = 0; i < _actionButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            _actionButtons[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < currentRoomActions.Length; i++)
        {
            _actionTexts[i].text = currentRoomActions[i].Description;
            _actionButtons[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        _bgAudio.clip = currentRoom.Clip;
        _bgAudio.Play();
    }

    private void EndGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex -1);
    }

    private void OnActionButton(byte index)
    {
        var currentAction = _roomInfo[_currentIndex].Actions[index];

        _currentIndex = currentAction.Index;
        _clickAudio.PlayOneShot(currentAction.ClickClip);

        if (_currentIndex >= _roomInfo.Length)
            EndGame();
        else
            SetRoomInfo();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        SetRoomInfo();

        for (byte i = 0; i < _actionButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            var index = i;
            _actionButtons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => OnActionButton(index));
        }
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("savedIndex", _currentIndex);
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        _currentIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("savedIndex");
    }
}


Когда открываю меню, в котором кнопки сохранения и загрузки выдает ошибку
(жалуется на строку var currentRoom = _roomInfo[_currentIndex];):
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
TextQuest.SetRoomInfo () (at Assets/Scripts/TextQuest.cs:57)
TextQuest.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TextQuest.cs:98)

Хотя до того момента как в меню не захожу ее нету. Помогите пожалуйста.

Скорее всего у вас на момент обращения к _roomInfo там просто пустой массив, т.е, туда ничего не передаётся. Попробуйте перед строчкой var currentRoom = _roomInfo[_currentIndex] вывести этот массив в Debug, и посмотреть, что там находится внутри

Он не "жалуется", а английским по серому пишет, что пошло не так. Debug.Log() в помощь.
